# incremental hashing output size

Tags: integers, hash-function, collision-detection

I've recently been looking into incremental hash functions (namely, [LtHash](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/227.pdf)). My purpose is to check set membership using a hash of particular element (incremental hashing allows that). The problem is that [reference implementation](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/experimental/crypto/LtHash.h#L54) and [ports](https://github.com/lukechampine/lthash) produce 2KB hash as a default size. it seems huge to me, my goal is to hash small inputs (up to 16bytes), and ideally I'd like to have < 32b hash as a result. While reading the original paper I can't wrap my head around what's required for this. I don't mind some number of collisions (<100), but I'd like to understand at least an approximate parameters/process for this. I'm not sure birthday paradox formula can be applied here.

What are my options? Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.